# Gridview Checkbox Update User on a new page

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am trying to update a user in a different page with textboxes.  But what I'm trying to do is select the user based on a Gridview.

So on the first page You see a gridview with a user list and checkboxes. You select a user with a check box and then hit the Edit User button.  Then it goes to a new page which allows you to edit the user in textboxes but populates the data because of the ID or another unique column.  How would I do this??

Here is the code I have so far:

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow gvrow in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox CheckBox1 = (CheckBox)gvrow.FindControl("chkSelect");
        if (CheckBox1.Checked)
        {
            //Go to new page to edit user
        }
        else
        {
            //Do nothing if not checked
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So you need to get the `ID` of the checked user, right?

Comment: yes thats what i need to do

Comment: Seems cumbersome, why not just have an "edit" link button ?

Comment: I did the same thing you mentioned sh1rts but I used Select. and used if checkbox selected and selectedindexchanged for gridview. and then passed it through a session id.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your checkbox is inside a `<asp:TemplateField>`.

So, in a `<asp:TemplateField>` you could add a `<asp:HiddenField />` to store the `ID` of the user. Then you can get the `ID` by getting the value of the `<asp:HiddenField />`

**ASPX markup**:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelect" runat="server" />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hfdUserID" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("id") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

**Code behind**:

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int userid = 0;
    foreach (GridViewRow gvrow in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox CheckBox1 = (CheckBox)gvrow.FindControl("chkSelect");
        if (CheckBox1.Checked)
        {
            userid = Convert.ToInt32(((HiddenField)gvrow.FindControl("hfdUserID")).Value);
            Response.Redirect("useredit.aspx?id=" + userid.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**: To get the user `ID` to the new page you can use the following and then use it accordingly

```
int userid = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]);
```

Comment: Sorry I'm pulling the ID from a SQL database also I want to response redirect to a new page and populate according to the sql ID or primary key

Comment: useredit.aspx but could I pass the ID through the URL? or is a hidden field better?

Comment: Through the URL is just fine. I updated my answer to be more complete

Comment: Thank you.  I added everything and i don't get errors but the button2 doesn't redirect me to new page.  Just does nothing.

Comment: if you have time, could you remote in through teamviewer? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Try to put a breakpoint and run your code in Debug mode to see how the code runs

Comment: i get App_Web_w5b2ghpd.dll!account_Default.Button2_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e) Line 38 C#

Comment: Everything seems to be fine with the code it just doesn't do anything i can't figure out why

Comment: This is the code that is messing it up         CheckBox CheckBox1 = (CheckBox)gvrow.FindControl("chkSelect");
        if (CheckBox1.Checked)

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that if the User's id is an integer, passing it unencrypted through the query string is *NOT* a good idea. Imagine if the user hits the page and adds a random number that happens to belong to a user.... then he could potentially edit that user without having permission. Unless you have authentication set up for this.

Comment: I used a session ID instead of all this.